# Use HTMLHelper::_ by calling a namespaced class

Tags: joomla-4.x, namespace, htmlhelper

In my component under Joomla! 4.0, I have the following call which returns:

> error JHtml componentname not found.

```
HTMLHelper::_(
    'componentname.link',
    'index.php?option=com_component&view=credits',
    Text::_('COM_COMPONENT_MYTEXT'),
    '',
    '',
    '',
    ''
);
```

I have a namespaced class called `ComponentName` under `Component\Name\Libraries\Html\Html`. How can I make HTMLHelper find the namespaced class of my component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by adding a class file under **/site/src/Service/Html/Grid.php** with the namespace `Mycomponent\Forum\Site\Service\Html;` in this class, I have some methods like `published()`.

Then in the file **/admin/src/Extension/MyComponent.php**, I added the class into the boot method:

```
public function boot(ContainerInterface $container) 
{
    $this->getRegistry()->register('grid', new Grid($container->get(SiteApplication::class)));
}
```

Then I can call the method like:

```
HTMLHelper::_('grid.published', $row, $item->published, '', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMLHelper needs to be told where to search for custom classes,
try adding HTMLHelper->addIncludePath('YOUR PATH') with the path to your component.

If you want you could load libraries/src/HTML/HTMLHelper.php and look around after line 126. That's where it goes looking for the custom class information.

It looks like you are attempting to make an href link, is this the case?

Comment: I use namespaced class in my component which are autloaded by Joomla! so this method addIncludePath() can't work in my case and by the way it's a method deprecated

Comment: I'm not sure HTMLHelper is the best function to use. What are actualy trying to get your override to do when it calls componentname.link?